# Error while trying to burn an audio CD with Brasero

Tags: brasero

I have a problem trying to burn an audio CD with brasero, every time I try to I get this error.[image] I really like using Brasero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to edit--> plugins, uncheck the normalization plugin, due to a bug between brasero and gstreamer 1.0